# Epplus Desktop Application - Unable to determine the identity of domain

Tags: vb.net, excel, epplus

I have just starting my excel interop code to epplus and did it when savng an excel document but I can't read an existing file. I searched but every result is related with web applications, I am developing a desktop application.
My code is so simple:

```
    Dim File As FileInfo = New FileInfo(DosyaAd)
Using package As New ExcelPackage(File)
    Dim She As ExcelWorksheet
    She = package.Workbook.Worksheets("BF")
End using
```

I got this error at: She = package.Workbook.Worksheets("BF")

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233264
  Message=Unable to determine the identity of domain.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._GetAccountingInfo(Evidence evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, Object& oNormalized)
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.GetAccountingInfo(Evidence evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, String& typeName, String& instanceName)
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Evidence domainEv, Type domainEvidenceType, Evidence assemEv, Type assemblyEvidenceType, Evidence appEv, Type appEvidenceType)
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
       at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder.GetCurrentStore()
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder..ctor()
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.GetDefaultIsolatedStorageFile()
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32 retryCount, String& fileName)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.DeflateEmulationTransform.Decompress(Stream source, Stream sink)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream..ctor(Stream baseStream, Stream tempStream, Int64 position, IDeflateTransform transformer)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.ChangeMode(Mode newMode)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
       at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
       at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBlock(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.GetWorkSheetXml(Stream stream, Int64 start, Int64 end, Encoding& encoding)
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.CreateXml()
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet..ctor(XmlNamespaceManager ns, ExcelPackage excelPackage, String relID, Uri uriWorksheet, String sheetName, Int32 sheetID, Int32 positionID, eWorkSheetHidden hide)
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets..ctor(ExcelPackage pck, XmlNamespaceManager nsm, XmlNode topNode)
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.get_Worksheets()
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.GetDefinedNames()
       at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.get_Workbook()
.........
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue? I have a similar one I can't get out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If this workbook was generated in Microsoft Office or through the interop, the workbook may contain features that are not available through the EPPLus library, such as lines and themes, and others listed [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation).

I have not experienced it myself, but I have heard from others that issues come up when the Worksheet contains a lot of content.

Comment: Hello, The workbook contains just texts and numbers nothing else. Can you advice some other library simple and working?

Comment: Also, have you tried reading any from any different Excel files using EPPlus? It could be an issue with the file itself.